# Convert rails mysql SQL to work with postresql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have the following tags method which selects tags based on how many times they are used and then arrange them in that order. Code is based on the railscasts episode: http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging.

I changed my DB from mysql, where this was previously working, to postgres where you can see the error message produced in the stack trace.

How can I refactor this sql to work with postgresql?

```
def tags
   Tag.joins(:taggings).select('tags.*, count(tag_id) as "tag_count"').group(:tag_id).order('tag_count desc')
end
```

stack trace

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "tags.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT tags.*, count(tag_id) as "tag_count" FROM "tags" INNE...
               ^
: SELECT tags.*, count(tag_id) as "tag_count" FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "taggings"."tag_id" = "tags"."id" GROUP BY tag_id ORDER BY tag_count desc:
```

tag.rb

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :taggings
  has_many :questions, through: :taggings
  #omitted for brevity
```

tagging.rb

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :question
end
```

If anyone needs more code just shout.

Comment: A bit of "must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function" searching around here should get you the answers you need.

Comment: You were right, answer was in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding "tags.id" as the error message says to the group clause worked like a charm.

```
Tag.joins(:taggings).select('tags.*, count(tag_id) as "tag_count"').group("tags.id").order('tag_count desc')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error message gives you SQL composed by rails

```
SELECT tags.*, count(tag_id) as "tag_count"
FROM "tags"
    INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "taggings"."tag_id" = "tags"."id"
GROUP BY tag_id
ORDER BY tag_count desc
```

this is MySQL only syntax, and I must say I've never liked that MySQL allows that, it's unclear how columns which are not in `group by` should be shown in th resultset. Should it be min? should it be max?

I suggest you just to choose only columns you need in you result, and don't use `select *`. Looks like you don't need `tags.id` in your result at all (because you're already have `taggings.tag_id` and there're equal because of `inner join`). I think it'd better for you if you try to understand why do you getting this error and rewrite your SQL in proper ANSI syntax, for example:

```
select tags.name as tag_name, count(*) as "tag_count"
from tags
    inner join taggings on taggings.tag_id = tags.id
group by tags.name
order by tag_count desc
```